# Uninstantiated function/class template ast is not generated by clang

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang, libtooling

I am working on a C/C++ parser based on clang libtooling.
I use the AST generated by clang to parse the code.
Recently what I observed is that for a template class or function which is not instantiated clang does not generate AST for that class or function.

Example:
Code and the corresponding AST is shown below

```
template <typename T>
int serializeToJson(const T& value)
{
    using OutputStream = std::ostream;
    using OutputArchive = std::istream;
    int i;
    int k;
    return i + k;
}

template <class T>
class TClass
{
    T *ptr;

    TClass() { ptr = nullptr; }
};
```

[image]

Did anybody encounter such behavior? Is this the expected behavior. I want to do the static analysis of code and I don't care whether the template classes/functions are instantiated or not. Without AST I won't be able to do the correct static analysis.

Would you please help me to fix this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Hemant

Comment: You probably used `-fdelayed-template-parsing` or `-fms-compatibility`, which doesn't parse template definition bodies.

Comment: Thank you very much, Johannes, using **-fno-delayed-template-parsing** solved the problem.