# How to completely parse cpp file by clang?

Tags: c++, clang, libclang

I'm using clang in python to parse c++ code file, here's my code:

```
def traverse(node, depth):
    print("%s%s %s" % ("|   " * depth, str(node.kind), node.spelling))
    for n in node.get_children():
        traverse(n, depth + 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
    parser = index.parse("M3UParser.cpp")
    cursor = parser.cursor
    traverse(cursor, 0)
```

it works well in the following c++ code:

```
static ssize_t FindNextUnquoted(
    const AString &line, char what, size_t offset){...}
```

But it can't parse the following code:

```
status_t M3UParser::parseStreamInf(
    const AString &line, sp<AMessage> *meta){...}
```

It appears to just skip this kind of code.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Are the `#include` correct for cpp files?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42466963